# How to find the first focusable component in a container?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to programatically set a focus on the first component of a given container. What's the best way to do it?

A couple of notes:

- I haven't found any appropriate method on `IFocusManager` / `IFocusManagerContainer` interfaces. Ideally, there would be `IFocusManagerContainer#getFirstFocusableComponent()` but there is no such method.
- The "first" component is the one that would receive focus if you were on some component just before the container and pressed TAB. It is not necessarily the first focusable child of the container (tab order plays role here).
- I'd like the solution to perform well. I'm not particularly keen on traversing display list, I still hope there is some better way.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you seem to want a dynamic way, what happens if you manually fire a Keyboard event for a 'tab' press on the component's CreationComplete?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. My use case is that I have a container full of TextInputs and other UI component somewhere on the screen and after a button click in a different part of the screen, I need to set focus to the first TextInput inside the container.

Comment: And how about recursive looping over components and returning first component which is focusable?

Comment: Eugeny, the first component that you will retrieve by traversing the display list may not be the visually first component, i.e. the component that the user perceives as the first one. Plus, the logical order may be influenced by tabIndex. FocusManaged does some pretty interesting computations to find out the first / next component but unfortunately doesn't expose them via an API.